# Android - Installing Mp4Parser without Maven

Tags: android, audio, video, mp4, mp4parser

It's supposed to be very simple, but for a day I couldn't find a solution.
I'm trying to follow the example in http://andrey.chernih.me/2014/06/28/video-recording-and-processing-in-android/ ( Muxing Audio )

So I've added to my project's libs directory both

aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar
and
isoparser-1.0.6.jar
which were found through https://code.google.com/p/mp4parser/ ( Using without Maven )

But I can't implement "AudioMuxer" in my class.

What am I missing ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you gotta add it to your gradle file so it knows it's should be added:

```
compile files('libs/<filename>.jar')
```

[Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library)

Comment: I don't use a gradle file, I simply use a basic project created in Eclipse.

Comment: oh, so in that case my advice is the same I would give to anyone else. Stop using Eclipse and move to Android Studio. Not only the ADT plugin is not supported any more by the Android team at Google and you will invariably start having issues moving forward, but also AndroidStudio is faster, more stable, more configurable, more focused, etc, etc.

Comment: I wish, can't of as of today... I hope Eclipse is still good enough for those .jar files .

Comment: I know there's a way on since setting menu to do it. But I honestly don't remember, I've abandoned Eclipse 2 years ago already